# Creating Dispatch in BOT framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to create a Dispatch model for BOT framework using Commandline.

As soon as I enter 
`dispatch init -n <filename-to-create> --luisAuthoringKey "<your-luis-authoring-key>" --luisAuthoringRegion <your-region>` after adding necessary details it ask `Please enter your bot secret`

I am on version `1.5.1` of dispatch.

What is this bot secret ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an older version of Dispatch CLI. In older iterations of the bot framework, we used to make use of `.bot` files, which could be secured using a "`bot secret`". `.bot` files have no since been deprecated, however.

**Be sure to update (`npm install -g botdispatch`) to the latest version.**

Today, using version `1.5.1` (you can see version by typing `dispatch --version`), you should be able to create a dispatch doing something like the following:

```
dispatch init -n MyDispatch --luisAuthoringKey "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --luisAuthoringRegion westus
dispatch add -t luis --id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -n HumanResources -v review -k xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
dispatch add -t luis --id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -n Weather -v 0.1 -k xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
dispatch create --dispatch MyDispatch.dispatch
```

Comment: I tried the steps you mentioned and I also have the same version 1.5.1. but after the first step I get "Please enter your bot secret"

Comment: hmm, I wonder if a different bot framework CLI is interferring somehow? Because after running the 1st command, you should get "MyDispatch.dispatch created", that's it

Comment: Well I figured it out, I have to change the directory where the bot resides. I was trying to run the command a t a different location.

Comment: Ha, awesome :) I had pinged the Dispatch CLI Team to see if they had any ideas. I'll let them know what it was ultimately ::thumbsup::